# Entity Framework Core Sqlite in-memory throws SQLite Error 5: 'unable to delete/modify user-function due to active statements'

Tags: sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a small test service developed with ASP.NET Core 6.0 and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite v6.0, which is comprised of a couple of entities and a join table.  However, I've started experiencing the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException' in Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.dll: 'SQLite Error 5: 'unable to delete/modify user-function due to active statements'.'
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.CreateFunctionCore[TState,TResult](String name, Int32 arity, TState state, Func`3 function, Boolean isDeterministic)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.CreateFunction[T1,T2,TResult](String name, Func`3 function, Boolean isDeterministic)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection.InitializeDbConnection(DbConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteRelationalConnection..ctor(RelationalConnectionDependencies dependencies, IRawSqlCommandBuilder rawSqlCommandBuilder, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Set[TEntity]()
   at TestProject.AvailabilityService.Persistence.AvailabilityDbContext.get_GroupsOfPeople() in /Users/ram/Development/TestProject/src/Persistence/AvailabilityDbContext.cs:line 18
```

Googling for this particular error message came up empty.  Does anyone have any insight on what might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are running into is caused by trying to access Sqlite from multiple threads. Concurrency is supported up to a point (when read-only operations are performed) but once you start inserting or updating records things get tricky. The error (5) corresponds to documentation on Sqlite's result and error codes page:

https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#busy

> The SQLITE_BUSY result code indicates that the database file could not be written (or in some cases read) because of concurrent activity by some other database connection, usually a database connection in a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

EF Core source code shows that you have used the same `DbConnection` while defining `DbContextOptions`. It may cause problems with concurency if the same connection is used concurrently.

Use connection string instead.

[Link to source code](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/98bd7ab9d639ac19832192351f3c9fbfa7020d8b/src/EFCore.Sqlite.Core/Storage/Internal/SqliteRelationalConnection.cs#L48)